# Snowpipe getting auto paused and auto ingestion not working

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowpipe to auto ingest data into raw tables. I am using auto_ingest=true as well but  the data is not getting loaded as expected.
On further checking, found that the respective snowpipe is in paused state. However, I have not manually paused the pipes.
Has anyone faced this issue? or any suggestions on how can I troubleshoot to find out the cause why pipe is getting paused on its own.

Comment: Have you setup the cloud platform portion of the auto ingest?  Was the pipe ever working or is this the initial state of the pipe?

Comment: Yes, the setup has been done. The pipe is working fine when we resume it manually. But the issue is it is getting auto paused after some point of time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly this issue comes when you clone the Source DB to newer one,  CLONING the Database makes the PIPE in STOPPED State in cloned DB.
So to make PIPE running in the CLONE DB, we need to execute the below command:
ALTER PIPE mypipe SET PIPE_EXECUTION_PAUSED = FALSE